# How to add a custom attribute to a FabricJS object with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, fabricjs

When creating a new FabricJS object with a custom attribute whill result in a TypeScript error that the custom attribute does not exist in the IObjectOptions that IRectOptions extends from. How can I **globally** extend the IObjectOptions with a custom attribute?

```
const workarea = new fabric.Rect({
  id: "workarea",
  width: 250,
  height: 150,
});
```

When I hover over the "id: workarea" the following error appears:

> Argument of type '{ id: string; width: number; height: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IRectOptions'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'IRectOptions'.

Comment: try `const workarea = new fabric.Rect({
  id: "workarea",
  width: 250,
  height: 150,
} as any);`

Answer (score 2):

`id` is not a recognized property on [`IRectOptions`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/117e89479b314f9f824901b01d61734b0c016d78/types/fabric/fabric-impl.d.ts#L4129): the rectangle's constructor object options argument.

However, you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to assign your custom properties to an instance of [`Rect`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/117e89479b314f9f824901b01d61734b0c016d78/types/fabric/fabric-impl.d.ts#L4142). Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwGYEMBGVgGMC+clQQhwDkqG2JA3AFA1YQB2AzvAO7QDWKUApinAC8cAPJoAVrywwAdCmbNgAc0YAKGnDiNebfOkxYZAJSkxVCDZrhtgAExgALAFxwATAFYADABpLmh7zKDjAuAIxevpo4AJSRiHYuAEQcUNx8KIk4vtG0NClp-LQA9EUAegD8dPk8-DJ2tFaNJRU0QA)

```ts
import {fabric} from 'fabric';

const workarea = Object.assign(
  new fabric.Rect({
    width: 250,
    height: 150,
  }),
  {id: "workarea"},
);

workarea;
//^? const workarea: fabric.Rect & { id: string; }

workarea.id;
       //^? (property) id: string
```

---

See also: [fabricjs/fabric.js#6917 - How to add custom attributes to Fabric objects and retain my new attributes when the objects are converted to JSON?](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/6917)

Answer (score 2):

use [Typescript Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation)

```
declare module 'fabric/fabric-impl' {
    export interface IObjectOptions {
        id?: string;
    }
}
```